# Как вернуть цвет измененной кнопке при нажатии другой кнопки

Tags: swift, uicollectionview

Есть несколько кнопок, идентифицируемых по title. Когда нажимаю на кнопку, ее цвет меняется. Нажимая на следующую кнопку, предыдущая должна менять свой цвет обратно, а новая - менять цвет. Кнопки находятся в Collection View. Помогите, пожалуйста.

```
switch String(sender.title(for: .normal)!) {
    case "÷":
        mathSign = "÷"
        sender.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.1995130565, green: 0.9137254902, blue: 0.4666666667, alpha: 1)
        sender.setTitleColor(#colorLiteral(red: 0.1764705882, green: 0.1882352941, blue: 0.2784313725, alpha: 1), for: .normal)
    case "×":
        mathSign = "×"
        sender.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.1995130565, green: 0.9137254902, blue: 0.4666666667, alpha: 1)
        sender.setTitleColor(#colorLiteral(red: 0.1764705882, green: 0.1882352941, blue: 0.2784313725, alpha: 1), for: .normal)
    case "-":
        mathSign = "-"
        sender.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.1995130565, green: 0.9137254902, blue: 0.4666666667, alpha: 1)
        sender.setTitleColor(#colorLiteral(red: 0.1764705882, green: 0.1882352941, blue: 0.2784313725, alpha: 1), for: .normal)
    case "+":
        mathSign = "+"
        sender.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.1995130565, green: 0.9137254902, blue: 0.4666666667, alpha: 1)
        sender.setTitleColor(#colorLiteral(red: 0.1764705882, green: 0.1882352941, blue: 0.2784313725, alpha: 1), for: .normal)


    default:
        print("Error")
    }[![на картинке изображены кнопки][1]][1]
```

Comment: Как решение, можно перед установкой цвета все кнопки сбрасывать в базовый цвет.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я бы сделал следующим образом:

```
enum Method: String {
case plus = "+"
case minus = "-"
case multiplication = "×"
case division = "÷"
case undefined
}

var currentMethod: Method = .undefined {
    didSet {
      resetAll()
      switch currentMethod {
      case .plus:
          //configure plus
      case .minus:
          //configure minus
      ....
      }
   }
}

func resetAll() {
// Функция делает все элементы без выделения
}


....Ваш текуший код...

self.currentMethod = Method.init(rawValue: sender.title(for: .normal)) ?? .undefined
```